# Using VBA Excel to create Scatter Plot

Tags: vba, excel

This is my VBA code to create a scatter plot in Excel:

```
Sub createmychart()
    Dim Chart1 As Chart
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
    With Chart1
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("usd_download data").Range("A2:B26001")
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    End With
End Sub
```

However, it ended up like this:

[image]

But I would like to have a graph like this:

[image]

I tried a lots but cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: I wonder if putting `.ChartType` before `.SetSourceData` might help Excel parse the data into X and Y columns.

Answer (score 8):

Without knowing what your data looks like, your code appears to have two series of data while you want just one.

```
Sub createmychart()
    Dim Chart1 As Chart
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
    With Chart1
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        'Change to what your series should be called
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Values"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=usd_download data!$A$2:$A$26001"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=usd_download data!$B$2:$B$26001"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Cronos, thanks for your comment. the data just simply has 2 columns, 1st column is USD, with numbers from A2 to A26001, and the 2nd column is Downloads, with numbers from B2 to B26001. Can I ask what is "NewSeries"?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the chartobject, chart and SeriesCollection as well. NewSeries is the method to add one Series in the SeriesCollection collection, and since it's only one series, so you can use SeriesCollection(1) to refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (sorry different cell ranges but u get the idea)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xrng As Range
Dim yrng As Range


Set xrng = Range("A12:A17")
Set yrng = Range("B12:B17")

Dim Chart1 As Chart
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add

 With Chart1
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        'Change to what your series should be called
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Values"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xrng
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = yrng

    End With

End Sub
```